# Почему excel округляет дробную часть?

Tags: excel, vba

```
If balance < 0 Then Cells(i, 3) = Abs(balance) \ 100 * Range("E5")
```

Если баланс = -10, а E5 = 1, то в ячейку должно попасть 0.01, я же получаю 0. Кол-во дробных знаков в ячейке = 2. Если же проставлю -100, на выходе 1.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит? Почему не вводит число с дробной частью?

Comment: Если выполняется условие `balance < 0`, то в ячейку `Cells(i, 3)` пишем вычисленное значение. Если условие не выполняется, то **вычисление не происходит**. А теперь вопрос: как Вы умудряетесь получать 0 или 1, если и 10, и 100 больше нуля? Что в рукаве прячете?

Comment: @vikttur Извиняюсь, изначально минусовое значение. -10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"\" -
Результатом является целочисленное частное expression1 деление на expression2 , которое отклоняет остаток и оставляет только целую часть. Это называется усечением.

"/" - ответ

Answer (score 0):

В обратную сторону знак измените и будет вам с остатком - "/", так же можете самостоятельно определить количество знаков после запятой, использовав функцию Round(число, кол-во_знаков)